# Image added with jquery is not showing in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit

I create an image node with jquery and want to show it as a bigger version on top of the original.
The copied image does not show up in Chrome and Safari, but works in Internet Explorer and Firefox. The console does not report errors. The inspector shows the the cloned image element with all the right css properties, but gives the element a 0 x 0 pixels size.

I don't see any css rules that would hint to a 0x0 size.

here is a screenshot illustrating the situation
[image: illustration of situation with inspector]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhiPf.png)

here is a link to demo the behaviour, try clicking on the image with firefox and chrome:
[download.toastlab.ch/segtest](http://download.toastlab.ch/segtest)

---

edit:

the Javascript code that creates the element:

```
$('.streamcontent').on('click', 'img.clickable', function () {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $(this).attr('src');
    var w = img.width,
        h = img.height;
    img = $(img).addClass('bigger');

    var tw = $(this).width();
    var th = $(this).height();

    var pos = $(this).position();
    var center = {
        top: pos.top + th / 2,
        left: pos.left + tw / 2
    };

    img.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: pos.top,
        left: pos.left,
        width: tw,
        height: th,
        opacity: 0
    }).animate({
        top: center.top - h / 2,
        left: center.left - w / 2,
        height: h,
        width: w,
        opacity: 1
    }, 300, function () {
        $('body').one('click', function () {
            img.animate({
                top: pos.top,
                left: pos.left,
                width: tw,
                height: th,
                opacity: 0
            }, function () {
                img.remove();
            });
        });
    });
    $(this).parent().append(img);

});
```

Comment: Pages look the same for me (image appears fine) in chrome 21.0 and IE 10.0.84.

Comment: It's strange, I got `Chrome 21.0.1180.83 m` :/

Comment: @MaxPRafferty Just out of curiosity, do you have a 64bit version of chrome? (Open Task Manager and in processes tab search for `chrome.exe`. See if there is a `*32` beside the process name)

Comment: @Roman My version of chrome is 32 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

There is a CSS rule that specifies a maximum size (with `max-width` and `max-height`), I needed to override that rule to allow the bigger image... to be bigger.

To do this I overwrote max-width & height with a ridiculously high value (999999999px). It seems like this value *crashed* the "webkit renderers image size calculation", leaving the image size at 0 x 0. Setting the value to 9999px resolved the problem

I don't know if this qualifies as webkit bug or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your JS code

```
$('.streamcontent').on('click', 'img.clickable', function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $(this).attr('src');
    var w = img.width, h = img.height;
    img = $(img).addClass('bigger');
    ...
```

I think you must change

```
var w = img.width, h = img.height;
```

by

```
var w = img.width(), h = img.height();
```

because width and height are function in object Image, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I thought width and height were Image attributes?

Comment: sorry I just found out what the problem was. Seems like I used a "too large value" in another CSS rule, overflowing something in the rendering engine. I'm writing an answer now.